# OneDrive Business: Folder shows green checkmark although directory is not completely synchronized

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive

OneDrive Business is syncing to the local file system.

In the file explorer, it often happens that a folder shows a green check mark, but when I go into the folder, then some of the content shows the blue "refreshing" checkmark and is still syncing.

IMHO this is a severe bug. You think the folder's content is already downloaded, but actually the content is still syncing.

Can this be prevented?

Comment: This may be just a short delay. Before you open the target folder, you can refresh your OneDrive for Business folder to get the latest status of files and folders.

Comment: @HerbGu_MSFT No it's not a short delay. The directory might be gigabytes in size and the syncing can take hours.